# Update Angular View after resource post

Tags: angularjs

Here is my problem! I use `$resource` API to post data from the client side to the server side. After the server side successfully updates the database, I kinda hope my data in view will be updated.

I chose to achieve this with:

```
$scope.magazines = Magazines.query();

$scope.addMagazine = function() {
   var magazine = new Magazines({...payload data});
   Magazines.save(magazine, function() {
   $scope.magazines = Magazines.query();
});
};
```

Magazines is a defined ngResrouce factory.

This code works fine. My only problem is, whenever I activate this function (through mouseclick), the view flashes (refreshes) once. It is a really really bad user experience.

I wonder if there is any other way to add the new "magazine" to the scope without refreshing the entire `$scope.magazines` ?

By the way, the api at the backend will add a few properties (like created time, or id to it).  Even if I write code to get the last added item (a different factory method I suppose), I'll still have to add it to the `$scope.magazines` and I don't know how to do that.

Any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `push` the new `Magazine` onto the existing `$scope.magazines` (assuming it's an Array)

```
var magazine = new Magazines({...payload data});
$scope.magazines.push(magazine);
```

Comment: This does work! But it seems like when I call refer to magazine inside the success callback, it does not contain any additional information that I have assigned to it with `new Magazines()`.

Comment: Hmm...odd...verify that the Magazines() function is correct first, thennn...hmm...not sure after that. Seems like the problem would lye there.